# SceneKit: improve performance of SceneView's hitTest function?

Tags: ios, performance, scenekit, hittest, sceneview

Our scene only has about 20 nodes. The code below lets the user pan, conducting a hit test on each pan -- the goal is to highlight blocks as the user pans around the screen.

However, it is noticeably sluggish on a iPhone 5S. It's not deterministic but happens often enough to be irritating (every 5-10 pans).

We considered using `hitTestWithSegment` since you could tightly bound the range for testing but believe that should be slower because you must first compute the two points required for the function.

Moreover, the `SCNHitTestClipToZRangeKey` option for `hitTest` should provide a comparable performance boost by tightening the hit range without requiring the computation of two additional points.

Any suggestions for speeding up the performance of `hitTest`?

```
func sceneViewPannedOneFinger(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Get pan distance & convert to radians
    let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)
    var xRadians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(translation.x))
    var yRadians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(translation.y))

    // Get x & y radians
    xRadians = (xRadians / 4) + curXRadians
    yRadians = (yRadians / 4) + curYRadians

    // Limit yRadians to prevent rotating 360 degrees vertically
    yRadians = max(Float(-M_PI_2), min(Float(M_PI_2), yRadians))

    // Set rotation values to avoid Gimbal Lock
    cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: yRadians)
    userNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: xRadians)

    // Save value for next rotation
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        curXRadians = xRadians
        curYRadians = yRadians
    }

    // Set preview block
    setPreviewBlock(sender)
}


private func setPreviewBlock(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {        
    let point = recognizer.locationInView(sceneView)
    let options = [SCNHitTestRootNodeKey: sceneView.scene!.rootNode, SCNHitTestClipToZRangeKey: 15, SCNHitTestSortResultsKey: true]
    let hits = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: options)
    print(hits.first?.worldCoordinates)
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried firstFoundOnly option?

Comment: Also, if you don't care about super precision, could you not use boundingBoxOnly option? From Apple's documentation: "The default value is false, specifying that hit-testing searches should test against node geometry. Specifying true for this option increases search performance at the expense of geometric accuracy."